# Preserve nids script add in migrate d2d

Tags: 7, migrations

What is the file name I have to add the following script in it?

> This is actually easy to do. In the prepare() function of the node
>   migration class, just set the nid and is_new to true:
>
> ```
> public function prepare($node, $row) {
>   // Preserve old nid so that old links to nodes using /node/nid still work
>   $node->is_new = TRUE;
>   $node->nid = $row->nid;
> }
> ```
>
> Source link:
>   [How can I preserve nids during a migration?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109649/how-can-i-preserve-nids-during-a-migration#109860)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, sometimes answers on stackexchange are misleading.  It doesn't look like ANY classes within migrate_d2d extend MigrateDestinationEntity, that invokes a "prepare" hook.  So I think the question itself is misguided.

Looking in the migrate code, it looks like any class that extends abstract class MigrateDestinationEntity can call this process function see
/migrate/plugins/destinations/entity.inc,

on line 140:

```
// Then call any entity-specific handlers
migrate_handler_invoke_all($this->entityType, 'prepare', $entity, $source_row);
```

Rather than trying to find a place to call this from DrupalNodeMigration, which will never call this function, what you need to do is add a mapping for nid, and a mapping for "is_new".

In your class that extends the DrupalNodeMigration class, in the __contruct() function, just make sure to add a mapping for nid and is_new.

```
$this->addFieldMapping('nid', 'nid');
$this->addFieldMapping('is_new')->defaultValue(TRUE);
```

Otherwise, nid will be automatically assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I understand why you're asking, that answer is not really clear, or very generic at best. Let's see if we can figure out what they meant.

The `prepare()` methods of Migration classes are invoked from the prepare() method found on the `MigrateDestinationEntity` class (migrate/plugins/destinations/entity.inc). In the case of a d2d node migration, the Migration class is `DrupalNodeMigration` (migrate_d2d/node.inc). Other d2d Migration classes, like `DrupalRoleMigration`, also implement a `prepare()` method. So, my conclusion would be that this code should be added in `DrupalNodeMigration`.

Disclaimer: I didn't test this, it is just my conclusion based on reading the answer and code.

I must add that editing the code of a contributed module is never recommended. A cleaner, but more time consuming way would be to create a new Migration class in a custom module, make it extend `DrupalNodeMigration`, and add the prepare method there. How to do that exactly is beyond the scope of this question.